# How to compare angular element with jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to implement click outside to hide dropdown inside directive, So I have this code:

```
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var selector = $(e.target).closest('.time-selector');
        if (!selector.length) { // || !selector.is(element)) {
            if ($scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.show = false;
            } else {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.show = false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

but it don't work (don't hide) when I click on different `.timer-selector` element, I've try to test if `!selector.is(element)` but this don't work.

So How can I test if my jQuery selected element is the same DOM node as angular directive element?

Don't know if that's relevant but my directive don't have `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution, in my case, my element is my directive tag and not `.time-selector`, so this code solve the problem:

```
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var selector = $(e.target).closest('.time-selector');
        if (!element.find('.time-selector').is(selector)) {
            if ($scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.show = false;
            } else {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.show = false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var selector = $(e.target).closest('.time-selector');
    if (!selector.length) { // || !selector.is(element)) {
        // adjust this line here to get the scope where .show is defined
        var $scope = selector.scope();
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.show = false;
        });

    }
});
```

This may or may not work depending on whether `selector.scope()` returns the scope where 'show' is defined. If this does not work, then find the element that defines the scope where 'show' is defined, and call .scope() on the jQuery element to get the scope.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting what exactly "element" contains. If it is something like

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

you may check for inequality with

```
selector[0] != element
```

$jQueryObject[index] returns the appropriate HTMLElement.

Comment: Element was my `<directive>`, probably my code in question will work when there was `replace: true`.